On the surjectivity of the direct image of exact sequence on projective bundles
I have seen Section 2 of 'The smoothing algebraic space curves'. On page 102, the authors use the following claim:
Let $C$ be a space curve, $N$ its normal bundle and $K$ the finite set of $\mathbb{P}(N)$, whose projection in $C$ is injective. Then we have a natural exact sequence on $$0\to J_K(1)\to O(1)\to O_K(1)\to 0.$$
If we consider the direct image of such sequence for $\pi:\mathbb{P}(N)\to C$, we have $$0\to \pi_*J_K(1)\to N\to \pi_*O_K(1)\to R^1\pi_*J_K(1)\to 0.$$
The authors claim that the injectivity of the map $K\to C$ implies $N\to \pi_*O_K(1)$.
I guess we can check on each fiber. Then we have $$O_\mathbb{P}^n(1)\to \pi_*\mathcal{O}_K|_x\to 0.$$ However, if the idea is true, I think it might hold for any finite subset $K\to C$. My questions are: How to prove this claim? Does a similar claim hold for any projective bundle and a closed subscheme whose projection in the base is a closed immersion?
